# Update Hard Drive backup on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to run an aws s3 sync command daily to update my hard drive backup on S3. Most of the time there will be no changes. The problem is that the s3 sync command takes days to check for changes (for a 4tb HDD). What is the quickest way to update a hard drive backup on S3?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to backup your own computer to Amazon S3, I would recommend using a Backup Utility that knows how to use S3. These utilities can do smart things like compress data, track files that have changed and set an appropriate Storage Class.

For example, I use Cloudberry Backup on a Windows computer. It does regular checking for new/changed files and uploads them to S3. If I delete a file locally, it waits 90 days before deleting it from S3. It can also handle multiple versions of files, rather than always overwriting files.

I would **recommend only backing-up data folders** (eg My Documents). There is no benefit to backing-up your Operating System or temporary files because you would not restore the OS from a remote backup.

While some backup utilities can compress files individually or in groups, experience has taught me to *never* do so since it can make restoration difficult if you do not have the original backup software (and remember -- backups last *years!*). The great things about S3 is that it is easy to access from many devices -- I have often grabbed documents from my S3 backup via my phone when I'm away from home.

**Bottom line:** Use a backup utility that knows how to do backups well. Make sure it knows how to use S3.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a backup tool that can synchronize with Amazon S3. For example, for Windows you can use Uranium Backup. It syncs with several clouds, including Amazon S3.

It can be scheduled to perform daily backups and also incremental backups (in case there are changes.)

I think this is the best way, considering the tediousness of daily manual syncing. Plus, it runs in the background and notifies you of any error or success logs.

This is the solution I use, I hope it can help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).